# How do I search the rotten tomatoes API with AngularJS

Tags: json, angularjs, rotten-tomatoes

I'm trying to create a search of the rotten tomatoes api using angularjs. I want to be able to type the query press enter or go (on a phone) then the api returns the result of the query.

I tried to attach the `$scope.search` to an input in the view. I know I'm doing something wrong but due to my inexperience I can't think what to do. Looking for someone to kindly point me in the right direction.

View

```
<input placeholder="Search for it" ng-model="search">
```

Controller

```
ctrls.controller('resultsCtrl', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.search = 'query';
    $http.jsonp('http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json', {
        params: {
             page_limit: '5',
             page: '1',
             q: $scope.search,
             apikey: myKey,
             callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'
         }
    })
    .success(function (data) {
        $scope.results = data.movies;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use a function for that

```
ctrls.controller('resultsCtrl', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.search = 'query';
    $scope.fetchResults = function(){
      $http.jsonp('http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json', {
          params: {
               page_limit: '5',
               page: '1',
               q: $scope.search,
               apikey: myKey,
               callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'
           }
      })
      .success(function (data) {
          $scope.results = data.movies;
      });
    }
});
```

and call it from your view

```
<form ng-submit="fetchResults()">
    <input placeholder="Search for it" ng-model="search">
    <input type="submit" value="Go"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I knew it was something simple